# How to send `apns-collapse-id` using FCM when sending Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I've been trying to implement collapsable `Push Notifications` using a simple `POST` request to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`. As an example, let's say it's a simple `Notification` with the following body:

```
{
   "notification": {
      "title": "Your Title",
      "body": "Notification Body"
    },
   "to":deviceIDString
}
```

This works fine, as expected, and the device will get the notification. However I would like to add the `apns-collapse-id` and can't understand how to do so. It's supposed to go on the header, at least according to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) so I've tried, with no success, adding header fields to the request.

I've tried various ways, for example:

Adding the header to the `root` of the `body`:

```
`{
   "headers": {
     "apns-collapse-id": "1dfgbdfhgfnbv"
   },
   "notification": {
      "title": "Your Title",
      "body": "Notification Body"
    },
   "to":deviceIDString
}`
```

Adding apne and an header for them:

```
`{
   "apns": { 
     "headers": {
       "apns-collapse-id": "1dfgbdfhgfnbv"
      }
   },
   "notification": {
      "title": "Your Title",
      "body": "Notification Body"
    },
   "to":deviceIDString
}`
```

Among others like having a `data` field with `headers`, the `headers` inside the `notification` field and whatever else I could think of. So, I'm wondering, how did other people solve this or what's the correct way to send something on the `header` of the `FCM` request to the `apns` servers?

Answer (score 2):

[`apns-collapse-id`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#apnsconfig) *(set in the apns property as you did)* is only supported via HTTP v1 API. If you still want to use the Legacy API, you need to use [`collapse_key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#:%7E:text=e.g.%2C%20with-,collapse_key,-%3A%20%22Updates%20Available%22) instead. You can read this [summary](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#:%7E:text=Set%20the%20appropriate%20parameter,legacy%20protocols%20(all%20platforms)). I recommend migrating to the HTTP v1 API since the new features will be added to it.